# What does 'Si' mean with respect to network switches?

Tags: networking, cisco, ethernet, switch

I am seeing references to [Multilayer Switches with Si](https://conceptdraw.com/a1780c3/p11/preview/640) as in the network symbol below.
[image: Multilayer Switch with Si]
What does the 'with Si' qualifier mean?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It means [Silicon Switch Processor](http://docwiki.cisco.com/wiki/Internetworking_Terms:_Silicon_Switch_Processor_(SSP)) a high-performance [7000 series router](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/products/routers/7000-series-routers/index.html).

According to the answer from *dtlokee* in this [Cisco forum](http://www.techexams.net/forums/ccda-ccdp/21542-cisco-press-ccda-symbology.html), it does stand for SSP.

---

*They use the Si for the "silicon switching", I guess it's a bit dated but that is how they would represent a switch doing L3 switching in hardware. Now I think it goes without saying that multilayer switching is done in hardware. They also used a switch icon with an extra bit on the bottom that had 4 rectangles with lines between them to represent a L3 switch with the MFFC installed (going back to the 5000/5500 here)*

Comment: This is what I was taught.

Comment: The link you cite refers to Cisco 7000 series routers, but doesn't mention the Nexus 7K series of switches. I would think the use of the Si designation would be redundant on a switch given its logic is encoded in an ASIC already.

Comment: Nexus is a line of product of it's own. It has nothing to do with the Cisco 7000 series, a product that's End-of-Sale and End-of-Life. I added a link to the product description. I also changed switch to router...my bad.

Comment: Okay, but the question relates to switches, not routers.

Comment: See the edit to answer your question regarding switches vs routers.

Answer (score 0):

SI stands for the Standard Image. There is also an EI version which is the Enhanced Image.

[Source](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps628/prod_bulletin09186a00800b3089.html)

> The Cisco Catalyst® 2950 Series switches include two software image
>   versions that support different degrees of functionality—the Standard
>   Image (SI) and the Enhanced  Image (EI) Software. The version of
>   software depends solely on the model of switch  selected, with no
>   upgrade capabilities.
>
> The SI version is embedded in Cisco Catalyst 2950-12, 2950-24, and
>   2950SX-24 switches,  and supports basic Cisco IOS® functionality, Fast
>   Ethernet connectivity, and cluster  management.
>
> The EI version supports all that and more. The EI version of software
>   is embedded in  Cisco Catalyst 2950T-24, 2950C-24, and 2950G-12,
>   2950G-24, 2950G-48 switches, and  supports advanced intelligent
>   services, gigabit connectivity, and a richer set of  features. These
>   include Cisco Spanning-Tree Protocol enhancements for high
>   availability,  access control parameters (ACPs) for enhanced security,
>   and Differentiated Services Code  Point (DCSP) and rate limiting for
>   advanced quality of service.

Comment: and a detailed [comparison of the two](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/switches/ps628/prod_bulletin09186a00800b3089.html) here

Comment: That would be `SI` not `Si` (like the periodic table sign for silicon, see the other answer).

Comment: I'm not sure you're correct in this context. Do you have any links to documentation that indicates this is what is meant in the graphic icon shown? Can you find an example of an icon with an Ei in the middle?

Comment: No, the Catalyst 2950 did not exist in the 1990s, and that is when the Si icon in question was first marketed.  Perhaps you got the idea that it's "Standard Image" from [Leo Laohoo's answer](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10831151/meaning-si-cisco-icons); while Leo is usually spot-on, in this case he's quite full of poo.  The answer from acampbell on the same page is correct (and provides proof).